# Rename all sub-directories and files of main folder

Tags: bash

I want to rename all sub-directories and files of my main folder - removing all whitespaces in the name.

For example:

```
/MyMainFolder/New Folder
becomes
/MyMainFolder/NewFolder

/MyMainFolder/New Compressed Folder (Zip)
becomes
/MyMainFolder/NewCompressedFolder(Zip)

/MyMainFolder/New Folder/temp/Some Random Folder
becomes
/MyMainFolderser/NewFolder/temp/SomeRandomFolder
```

I came up with the following bash script in order to do so but it doesn't seem to help -

```
find ~/MyMainFolder/ -name '* *' -execdir rename " " "" {} +
```

Comment: Which version of `rename` do you have?  It looks like it must be the pathetically^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H under-powered one rather than the Perl-based one.  With the Perl-based one (sometimes called `prename`), you'd use `-execdir rename 's/\s+//g' {} +` to replace all strings of one or more white space characters (blanks, tabs, newlines, formfeeds, etc) with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
find ~/MyMainFolder/ -depth -name '* *' -execdir rename " " "" {} +
```

I guess you need a **depth**, to tell find to start with renaming the leaves. Else find will first find "a a", then "a a/b b", rename "a a" to "aa" and then fail to find "a a/b b" which is meanwhile "aa/b b".